# How to add an attribute to an element if container div has a specific class?

Tags: jquery, addclass

```
<div class="colorClass">
<a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

How can I add an attribute to an  tag that is inside a div container with class "colorClass"?

Answer (score 1):

This line of code should select the **first(and only the first)** *active* element **directly** inside the specified div and changes the href attribute's for example.

```
$(".colorClass > a").attr("href","http://yoursite.com");
```

Comment: Instead of selecting first do you think if I did `$('div.colorClass a').attr('data-optin-slug', 'xxxx');` if would be better?

Comment: Removing the > does not rule out that it's not selecting the first. It means you want to select the **first specified element directly inside** the _.colorClass_ div.
For example, if you have an other div, inside the _.colorClass_ div, and you have the a element inside that, you cannot select the a element, because it's not directly inside the _.colorClass_ div. If you remove the >, you can select in the element in the case written above.
Removing the > in this case doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Sajad data should not be set using attr, but yes there is nothing in your question that requires the answer to specify targeting the direct descendant only.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the following, not sure if it's proper.

```
$('div.colorClass a').attr('data-optin-slug', 'xxxx');
```

Comment: You are using data incorrectly. While it may appear as an attribute on page load, it is stored in a global array, and that array is updated, not the HTML. Not only will you run into problems when using code that uses data correctly, re-writing HTML is much slower that updating the data array. https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @Popnoodles I see your point. I should be using prop.

Does the same apply to using .removeProp in place of .removeAttr?

Comment: no you shouldn't be using attr or prop. You should be using `.data()` Read the docs https://api.jquery.com/data/